# CSS positioning

Tags: html, css

On my HTML document, I have a message and radio-box. I want both to be displayed side by side. Message left, top aligned and radio-box right, top aligned. I tried using CSS "display:inline" for the container  but that did not work. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="test-div">
  <p>Current time:  <span id="current-time"></span></p>
  <fieldset id="fieldset-options">
  <legend>My Options</legend>
  <input id="opt1" type="radio" name="grp-options" value="1">
  <label id="label-opt1" for="opt1">First Option</label><br/>
  <input id="opt2" type="radio" name="grp-options" value="2">
  <label id="label-opt2" for="opt2">Second Option</label><br/>
  <input id="opt3" type="radio" name="grp-options" value="3">
  <label id="label-opt3" for="opt3">Third Option</label><br/>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#test-div {
    font-size : 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    //display: inline;        
}


#test-div #fieldset-options legend {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight : bold;
}

#test-div #fieldset-options {
    font-size : 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
```

This is [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/R6HHK/). Please tell me how to arrange this properly.
    ​

Comment: It's all explained here: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms

Comment: @Diodeus, appreciate the link going through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve. Is it something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/R6HHK/19/

I have simply given the `p` and the radiobox container a width, and the floated the elements.

Answer (score 1):

what about doing this:

add this code to your css:

```
#test-div > p{float:left;}
```

and then remove the position and width from your #test-div #fieldset-options selector.

is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Float the time left and the fieldset right.

```
#test-div p {
    float:left;
    margin:0;
}
#test-div fieldset {
    float:right;
}​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/R6HHK/35/)**

You'll want to clear (`clear:both`) the content that comes immediately after this otherwise other elements may float up under it.

Comment: Good point about clear. I experienced exactly the same thing that you are referring to.